# Сравнение элементов массива

Tags: php, массивы, php7

Есть ли в PHP функция, которая бы проверила, равны ли все элементы массива?
То есть:

```
 $i[0] == $i[1] == $i[2]
```

и так далее, элементов может быть `n`-ое количество.

Comment: Используйте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php если у вас элементы массива всегда числа или строки.

Comment: @Дмитрий, http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((count(array_unique($a)) === 1)
  .........

if (empty(array_filter($a, function($val) {return $val != $a[0]})))
  ................
```

Answer (score -2):

```
array_sum($a) == count($a) * $a[0]
```

Comment: например [3,0,0]

Comment: @rjhdby что например [3, 0, 0], тогда будет проверять 3 == 9, это false - алгоритм работает

Comment: ок, тогда [1,2,0]